# Windows 7 Process ID circular reference

Tags: c#, windows, recursion, process, windows-7

I'm observing that when recursively inspecting child process IDs with ManagementObjectSearcher, I can find some descendant process ID that matches the starting parent process. Should this be possible if the pid is unique to each instance of a process? This is in Windows 7, code written in C#.

The following is called with arg `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` and so is intended to end all processes spawned by it, but not itself.

```
private void KillSpawnedProcesses(int pid)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID=" + pid);
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        if(mo["ProcessID"] != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        {
            KillSpawnedProcesses(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"]));

            try
            {
                Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                proc.Kill();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            { /* process already exited */ }
        }
        else
        {
            //This line will occasionally be executed
            Log("Don't kill current process");
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: The PID doesn't change throughout the lifetime of a process. When the process terminates, that ID can be reused for another process. This can produce a cyclic graph over process IDs.

Comment: Try moving `Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid)` to the line before you recursively call `KillSpawnedProcesses`. That should keep the ancestor Process objects from getting reaped by the kernel's process manager.